# Elasticsearch match query on each separate value in a multi value field without nested

Tags: elasticsearch

For a multi-valued field, like this:

```json
PUT match_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "companies": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
POST match_test/_doc/1
{
  "companies": ["bank of canada", "japan games and movies", "microsoft canada"]
}
```

This query returns the document we inserted above:

```json
GET match_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "companies": {
        "query": "canada games",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to tell elastic to match to each item in the list separately?
I want the doc to match "bank of", "of America", "bank", "games", "Canada", but not "Microsoft games"

**I do not want to use nested documents or scripts**

Comment: Did you try nested field? I think nested will work for this. I can give an example if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find words that are far apart from each other but are still on the same array index , then you can use position_increment_gap.

When creating a mapping, set position_increment_gap of the field to 100. Elasticsearch will automatically index array data at each position with +100 in position for the data at the next index.
Then write a match_phrase query with slop 99.

```
PUT match_test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "companies": {
        "type": "text",
        "position_increment_gap": 100
      }
    }
  }
}

GET match_test/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "companies": {
            "query": "japan movies",
            "slop":99
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Read more about it here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/position-increment-gap.html

Comment: Thank you, it works! I thought that "match_phrase" only works where the tokens are in order, so "japan movies" is fine, however "movies japan" wouldn't match. It does match which is exactly what I want, but I don't understand why. any idea?

Comment: It is because the slop is very high. As per Elasticsearch docs,  phrase query matches terms up to a configurable slop (which defaults to 0) in any order. Transposed terms have a slop of 2. We are using a slop of 100 hence we can find words that are at a position gap of 100 or less from each other in any order.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, using a slop of 100 also matched when I used the last and first words of two different values ("movies microsoft"), changing to 99 fixed that as it no longer slips to the next value in the list

Comment: Oh, thanks!! I did not check that boundary case. Updated the answer :)